# Outputting Programmatically to MSword; sensing end of line

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, arabic

I'm trying to use the MSWord Interop Library to write a C# application that outputs specially formated text (isolated arabic letters) to a file.  The problem I'm running into is determining how many characters remain before the text wraps onto a new line.  I need the words to be on the same line, without wrapping, which is the default behavior. I'm finding this difficult because when I have the Arabic letters of the word isolated with spaces, they are treated as individual characters and therefore behave differently then connected words.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is MSWord mandatory OR would for example a PDF library be an option ?

Comment: any document, I just assumed word would be the best documented and easiest.

Comment: I assume you can't use a commercial library... this [one](http://geekswithblogs.net/JaydPage/archive/2011/11/02/using-itextsharp-to-correctly-display-hebrew--arabic-text-right.aspx) is free and seems to work although I never tried is myself.

Comment: I don't really have an issue outputting the characters themselves.  I'm more concerned with maximizing their size relative to the character limit of each line.

Comment: the linke I provided has not only some code but it uses a library called iTextSharp which is linked on that page...

Comment: Could you not add each character to your range and then check the number of lines in the range (something like this:  totalLineCount += range.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticLines);) When the line count changes, you know it has been wrapped, and can remove the last character or reformat accordingly.

Comment: @sga101 I implemented your suggestion thanks!  Please post it below so I can reward you the bounty.

Comment: @amadib I've posted my suggestion as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add each character to your range and then check the number of lines in the range

```
LineCount = range.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticLines);
```

When the line count changes, you know it has been wrapped, and can remove the last character or reformat accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know how this behaves today, but I've written something for the MSWork API when I was facing a somewhat weird fact. Actually you can't find that out. In MSWord, text in a document is always in paragraphs.

If you input text to your document, you won't get it in a page only, but this page will at least contain a paragraph for the text you wrote into it.

Unfortunately I can't figure this out again, because I don't have a license for MS Word these day.

Give it a try and look at the problem again in this way.

Hope this helps, and if not, please provide the code that generates the input and the exact version of MSWord.

Greetings,
Kjellski

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "Arabic letters of the word isolated with spaces" means exactly, but I assume that [non breaking space](http://www.infopackets.com/news/carols_corner_office/2006/20060125_insert_a_non_breaking_space.htm) is what you need.

[Here's more details.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)